# Instance of repeating data in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Lets say I have a table that looks like this:

```
table = (Key int, ID int)
```

I need to be able to number incrementally each repeating instance of the ID column.
For example, if we have a sample of data that looks like this:

```
ID
--
99
100
101
102
103
100
101
102
103
```

I need a query that can return the following results:

```
99    1
100   1
101   1 
102   1
103   1
100   2
101   2
102   2
103   2
```

I cannot seem to get this working. Can anyone help out?

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER` function:

```
SELECT
ID,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) RowNum
FROM Table
ORDER BY RowNum, ID
```

Sample results [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cc3ee/2)

Comment: Thanks. I was missing the "partition by" when i was trying to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a simple ROW_NUMBER(), unless I'm missing something:

```
SELECT ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, ORDER BY Key)
FROM Table
```